# Postgresql 10 jsonb to table with multiple rows

Tags: json, postgresql

Postgresql 10 jsonb to table with multiple rows

I have a a json array that is containing some "users" structure. These json arrays are stroe in a Postgresql database and I would like to get all lines (for all rows for all arrays).

Data sample:

My database instance:

```
docker run --name postgresql-10 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres:10-alpine 

docker run -it --rm --link postgresql-10:postgres postgres:10-alpine psql -h postgres -U postgres
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Reports" (
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "report" JSONB NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("name", "timestamp")
)
;
```

Some data:

```
insert into "Reports" (timestamp, "name", "report")
  values ('2017-11-05'::timestamp, 
          'appA', 
          '{
         "dateComputed": "2017-11-06 10:06:29 UTC",
         "name": "appA",
         "users": [
           {
             "DATE": "2017-11-03",
             "EMPLID": "415",
             "NAME": "Smith"
               },
               {
             "DATE": "2017-11-03",
         "EMPLID": "4",
         "NAME": "Jane"
           },
           {
             "DATE": "2017-11-03",
             "EMPLID": "31",
             "NAME": "Doe"
           }
         ]
      }'::jsonb
         ) ;

insert into "Reports" (timestamp, "name", "report")
  values ('2017-11-04'::timestamp, 
          'appA', 
          '{
         "dateComputed": "2017-11-04 11:34:13 UTC",
         "name": "appA",
         "users": [
               {
             "DATE": "2017-11-03",
         "EMPLID": "4",
         "NAME": "Jane"
           },
           {
             "DATE": "2017-11-03",
             "EMPLID": "31",
             "NAME": "Doe"
           }
         ]
      }'::jsonb
         ) ;

insert into "Reports" (timestamp, "name", "report")
  values ('2017-11-01'::timestamp, 
          'appA', 
          '{
         "dateComputed": "2017-11-01 02:32:49 UTC",
         "name": "appA",
         "users": [
               {
             "DATE": "2017-11-01",
         "EMPLID": "415",
         "NAME": "Smith"
           },
           {
             "DATE": "2017-11-01",
             "EMPLID": "31",
             "NAME": "Doe"
           }
         ]
      }'::jsonb
         ) ;


insert into "Reports" (timestamp, "name", "report")
  values ('2017-11-03'::timestamp, 'appB', '[{"other": "useless"}]'::jsonb) ;
```

What I would like is following table listing all users matching "Reports" whose "name" is 'AppA' :

```
+------------+-------+--------+
| DATE       | NAME  | EMPLID |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-03 | Smith | 415    |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-03 | Jane  | 4      |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-03 | Doe   | 31     |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-03 | Jane  | 4      |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-03 | Doe   | 31     |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-01 | Smith | 415    |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-01 | Doe   | 31     |
+------------+-------+--------+

+------------+------------+-------+--------+
| timestamp  | DATE       | NAME  | EMPLID |
+------------+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-05 | 2017-11-03 | Smith | 415    |
+------------+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-05 | 2017-11-03 | Jane  | 4      |
+------------+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-05 | 2017-11-03 | Doe   | 31     |
+------------+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-04 | 2017-11-03 | Jane  | 4      |
+------------+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-04 | 2017-11-03 | Doe   | 31     |
+------------+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-03 | 2017-11-01 | Smith | 415    |
+------------+------------+-------+--------+
| 2017-11-03 | 2017-11-01 | Doe   | 31     |
+------------+------------+-------+--------+
```

When I am only matching a single row then I am able to use jsonb_to_recordset to get all json lines matching that row. 
For instance when filtering on latest timestamp column by creating a view:

```
CREATE INDEX "ReportsGIN" on "Reports" USING gin ("report") ;

CREATE VIEW "Reports_Latest_timestamp"
AS
SELECT  "name"
       , max("Reports"."timestamp") AS "timestamp_latest"
FROM "Reports"
GROUP BY "name"
;

CREATE VIEW "Reports_Latest"
AS
SELECT   "Reports"."name"
       , "Reports"."report"
       , "Reports"."timestamp"
FROM "Reports"
WHERE ("Reports"."timestamp" = (SELECT "Reports_Latest_timestamp"."timestamp_latest" FROM "Reports_Latest_timestamp" WHERE "Reports_Latest_timestamp"."name" = "Reports"."name"))
;

select *
from
jsonb_to_recordset
(
 (select report#>'{users}'
  from "Reports_Latest" 
  where "name" = 'appA' 
) 
) as x(
        "EMPLID" integer
      , "NAME" text
      , "DATE" timestamp with time zone

)
;

 EMPLID | NAME  |          DATE
--------+-------+------------------------
    415 | Smith | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
      4 | Jane  | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
     31 | Doe   | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
(3 rows)
```

jsonb_to_recordset is working as expected.

**How can I use jsonb_to_recordset to list lines for all "reports" row?**

An answer to display "timestamp" on "Reports_Latest" would be (but still no clue for full "Reports" lines):

```
select  t."timestamp"
      , r."EMPLID"
      , r."NAME"
      , r."DATE"
from
(
  select "timestamp", report#>'{users}'
  from "Reports_Latest" 
  where "name" = 'appA' 
) as t
, (
  select *
  from
    jsonb_to_recordset
    (
     (select report#>'{users}'
      from "Reports_Latest" 
      where "name" = 'appA' 
    ) 
    ) as x(
            "EMPLID" integer
          , "NAME" text
          , "DATE" timestamp with time zone

    )
  ) as r
;


      timestamp      | EMPLID | NAME  |          DATE
---------------------+--------+-------+------------------------
 2017-11-05 00:00:00 |    415 | Smith | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
 2017-11-05 00:00:00 |      4 | Jane  | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
 2017-11-05 00:00:00 |     31 | Doe   | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
(3 rows)
```

[SQL Fiddle on Postgresql 9.6 to quick test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cd4df/3/0)

---

**The solution provided by Breathe is:**

```
select r."timestamp", x.*
from "Reports" as r
cross join lateral jsonb_to_recordset (r.report#>'{users}')
 as x(
        "EMPLID" integer
      , "NAME" text
      , "DATE" timestamp with time zone

)
where r."name" = 'appA' 
;

      timestamp      | EMPLID | NAME  |          DATE
---------------------+--------+-------+------------------------
 2017-11-05 00:00:00 |    415 | Smith | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
 2017-11-05 00:00:00 |      4 | Jane  | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
 2017-11-05 00:00:00 |     31 | Doe   | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
 2017-11-04 00:00:00 |      4 | Jane  | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
 2017-11-04 00:00:00 |     31 | Doe   | 2017-11-03 00:00:00+00
 2017-11-01 00:00:00 |    415 | Smith | 2017-11-01 00:00:00+00
 2017-11-01 00:00:00 |     31 | Doe   | 2017-11-01 00:00:00+00
(7 rows)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cd4df/9/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, what you are trying to do is to generate as many record as there are users in one single row of "Reports". In your desired table structure, the first two columns are the first two columns from "Reports". So your query needs:

```
select a.timestamp, a."name"
FROM "Reports" a
```

Then you want to create a "subset" of records for each of these. This is acheivable by applying the functiont that generate the subset to litterally all the rows. The subset is generated by the function jsonb_to_recordset(), therefore :

```
SELECT a.timestamp, a."name", b. *
FROM "Reports" a
CROSS JOIN lateral jsonb_to_recordset(a.report->'Users')
as b("EMPLID" integer
      , "NAME" text
      , "DATE" timestamp with time zone)
```

EDIT: I added the cross join lateral

Comment: I would like to get all lines from "Reports" and not only from "Reports_Latest"

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I have removed the ",b. *". Error displayed is : ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 7: ;
        ^

Comment: can you try: SELECT * from Reports" a LEFT JOIN jsonb_to_recordset(a.report->'Users') as x("EMPLID" varchar, "NAME" varchar, "DATE" varchar)

Comment: `postgres=# SELECT * from "Reports" a LEFT JOIN jsonb_to_recordset(a.report->'Users') as x("EMPLID" varchar, "NAME" varchar, "DATE" varchar)
postgres-# ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 2: ;
        ^
`

Comment: Sorry I forgot it was a cross join lateral and not a simple left join. I edited the query. I ran it on your data and it works.